# How can I load a embedded ruby javascript file on pageload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

So, as I am sure you are all familiar with, you can have actions in Rails that call html.erb files. You can also set up actions to render remotely that call embedded ruby files (for example submitting a "post" form to the "posts" controller, handling it remotely, and calling a js.erb file to update elements in the page).

What I want to know is how to run a js.erb file when I'm running an action that loads a template (html.erb file). To explain, consider if I want to run a User Show page:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end
 end
```

Linking to `user_path(User.find(1))` will load `show.html.erb`, and all seems great.

But what if I want to click on a link to `user_path(User.find(1))` and load `show.html.erb` while also loading `show.js.erb`? If (and I hope it is) this is possible, how could I adapt the show definition to also load `show.html.erb` and `custom_js_file_name.js.erb`?

FYI: I'm using Rails 3.0.9 and 3.1.3 on two different applications, and assume that I would put `show.js.erb` or any others in the Users folder (*views/users/...*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default,

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

will only render the `show` view based on if it was requested via HTML, JSON, JS, etc.

I think what you are describing is better suited for the [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) method in Rails.  Typically, controllers use the different `format.(:format)` methods in the `respond` blocks to respond to a controller call based on what the request type was (JSON, HTML, JS, etc).

In your `show.html.erb` file:

```
<%= render "users/show.js" %>
```

This allows you to render any arbitrary file you want in another one of your views.  This also allows you to split up your large view files into smaller (reusable) pieces called partials (**note:** all partials are named with a `_` character at the beginning and are called via `<%= render :partial => "users/my_partial" %>` which would render the `_my_partial.some_format.erb` file)

Comment: will this execute the code as embedded javascript? (ie will a file containing alert('Hello World'); lead to an alert being shown

Comment: As long as you wrap it in the typical script tags and the DOM ready javascript wrapper, that rendered code will execute upon page load

Answer (score -1):

Try having the `show` action render the `show.js.erb` file when requested with a format of `js`.  That should get Rails to render the dynamic template; now link to it from the original `show.html.erb` with a javascript link tag.

In `show.html.erb`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= show_users_path(@user.id) -%>.js"></script>
```

I haven't tried this and the rendering of `show.js.erb` may put additional formatting that would be a problem.